# What library use Roambi app iPhone to draw chart?

Tags: iphone, graph, charts

Does anyone know what library is used in the iPhone application Roambi to draw charts?

http://www.roambi.com/

Answer (score 3):

That looks like it uses the excellent [Core Plot Framework](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/).

Comment: Is that speculation, or is there some evidence?

Comment: It's purely speculation.  Since all iOS binaries are encrypted, I have no way of dumping the classes to verify if that is true or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not Core Plot.

There are some charts in the app that don't conform to Core Plot.

Maybe Roambi has started from Core Plot and has edited the source or maybe he has developed a new library with Quartz 2D.

Answer (score 0):

The guy that owns the company created Xcelsius, in looking at it and knowing the performance of core-plot, I'm guessing this guy rolled his own, heavily adapted core-plot to be more efficient, or might even be using an OpenGL library.