# How to animate the pie charts developed using core-plot library?

Tags: iphone, core-plot

In the iPhone application Roambi, the pie chart shown can be animated to rotate with the user as if rotating a disc. We can hold and do lot of stuff with that.

Someone mentioned that the Roambi app was developed using core-plot library:

[What library use Roambi app iPhone to draw chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224269/what-library-use-roambi-app-iphone-to-draw-chart)

How can I manipulate a pie chart developed using Core plot?

Comment: If you're just doing pie charts, you might want to check out XYPieChart. It has animation and looks better (in my opinion) than CorePlot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick look at the Core Plot source code reveals that `CPPieChart`'s inheritance looks like this:

> [CPPieChart](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/browse/framework/Source/CPPieChart.h) : [CPPlot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/browse/framework/Source/CPPlot.h) : [CPAnnotationHostLayer](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/browse/framework/Source/CPAnnotationHostLayer.h) : [CPLayer](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/browse/framework/Source/CPLayer.h) : [CALayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html)

So you can see that in the end, `CPPieChart` is just a heavily subclassed `CALayer`. I might be entirely incorrect here, but there's nothing that indicates that this can't be animated like any other `CALayer`. Try the following code to rotate the layer by 360 degrees:

```
CABasicAnimation *rotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(360), 0, 0, 1);
rotation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:transform];
rotation.duration = 10.0f;
[pieChart addAnimation:rotation forKey:@"rotation"];
```

If you can get this working then its just a matter of reading the values from the accelerometer and converting them to rotation angles.

Answer (score 5):

For a simple pie chart, even with the aforementioned animations, Core Plot is not necessary. If you only want a Core Plot solution, then please disregard this answer. However, here is a simple solution that requires no external packages or even any frameworks.

Create a UIView called PieChartView. In PieChartView.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PieChartView : UIView {
    float zeroAngle;
    NSMutableArray *valueArray;
    NSMutableArray *colorArray;
}
@property (nonatomic) float zeroAngle;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *valueArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *colorArray;
@end
```

Then the implementation in PieChartView.m:

```
#import "PieChartView.h"

@implementation PieChartView
@synthesize zeroAngle;
@synthesize valueArray, colorArray;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // DETERMINE NUMBER OF WEDGES OF PIE
    int wedges = [valueArray count];
    if (wedges > [colorArray count]) {
        NSLog(@"INSUFFICENT COLORS FOR PIE CHART: Please add %d additional colors.",wedges-[colorArray count]);
        for (int i=[colorArray count] ; i<wedges ; ++i) {
            [colorArray addObject:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        }
    }

    // DETERMINE TOTAL VOLUME OF PIE
    float sum = 0.0;
    for (int i=0; i<wedges ; ++i) {
        sum += [[valueArray objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
    }
    float frac = 2.0*M_PI/sum;

    // DETERMINE CENTER AND MAXIMUM RADIUS OF INSCRIBED CIRCLE
    int center_x = rect.size.width/2.0;
    int center_y = rect.size.height/2.0;
    int radius = (center_x > center_y ? center_x : center_y);

    // DRAW WEDGES CLOCKWISE FROM POSITIVE X-AXIS
    float startAngle=zeroAngle;
    float endAngle=zeroAngle;
    for (int i=0; i<wedges; ++i) {
        startAngle = endAngle;
        endAngle += [[valueArray objectAtIndex:i] floatValue]*frac;
        [[colorArray objectAtIndex:i] setFill];
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, center_x, center_y);
        CGContextAddArc(context, center_x, center_y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, 0);
        CGContextClosePath(context);
        CGContextFillPath(context);
    }
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [valueArray release];
    [colorArray release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Now you can bind the float zeroAngle to the accelerometer in any way you wish to achieve the desired animation.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't know CorePlot, and it might be some use for me in the near future, so I just gave it a look. CorePlot is interesting and is *active*.

Concerning Animations with CorePlot:

1. CorePlot documentation mentions an [Animation system](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/HighLevelDesignOverview#Animations), **but it is not implemented yet**...
2. Even if based on `Core Animation`, it doesnt mean CorePlot graph will be easily animatable.

[Interesting reading on the topic on google groups.](http://groups.google.com/group/coreplot-discuss/browse_thread/thread/5b6b4dc7441e75c9/5abe965a69183cbb)

So here are your options (by my order of preference):

1. Look for another plotting library handling animations like Roambi does.
2. Implement your animations based on CorePlot (means a good understanding of this framework and `Core Animation`)
3. Do everything yourself, depending on what you want, again, *might be* not that hard... But `Core Animation` skills needed, again.

I doubt Roambi uses CorePlot, but if they do, they use it as a base with *TONS* of custom in house  code...

Comment: @PengOne thanks for editing my bad grammar, english is obviously not my main language ;)