# How to animate bar height growth in core plot?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, core-plot, bar-chart

I am developing a plotting app which uses core plot. I want to animate the bar-chart height growth. I haven't used CALayer animations before. I saw some details of it but couldn't find any way to fulfill my motive using that. Though I feel it can have a role to play as charts are highly sub classed CALayers. Please correct if I am wrong and guide me to use animations to show growth of bar charts.

Comment: Click [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13914064/1260976) to refer to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CABasicAnimation and michele's answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552520/how-do-i-animate-the-appearance-of-a-bar-chart-in-core-plot?rq=1) did the trick for me and the charts are animating smoothly now :)