# How do I create animated charts on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, charts

Is there a good third party framework available for creating animated charts and graphs on iPhone or iPad?

I'm looking to do something similar to what [FusionCharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/demos/Blueprint/) provides.  How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey this will be helpful [core Plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/)

Comment: core plots dont have animations http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241740/how-to-animate-the-pie-charts-developed-using-core-plot-library

Comment: @Ankit - If you read indragie's answer there, you can see that Core Plot does support animations, although you need to add them yourself using Core Animation.  Many simple effects are not hard to achieve that way.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually use FusionCharts from your iOS project with a webView to render the charts.

Take a look at this: http://www.fusioncharts.com/labs/iOS/FusionCharts_iOS_Nov2011.zip

Also, another very good library (free!) to work with JSON, JS, web services, etc is DHTMLX Touch: http://www.dhtmlx.com/touch/.

Good luck!

**UPDATE:** I just found this framework: http://www.shinobicontrols.com/

Native API for iOS.  Amazing performance.

Answer (score 1):

There are several commercial tools for iOS charting, some of which have interactive features.

- [ShinobiControls](http://www.shinobicontrols.com) - which has many interactive features as shown [in this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NxK1oE0vXog).
- [www.threedgraphics.com](http://www.threedgraphics.com)
- [iPhone Charting Library for iPhone Objective-C](http://www.keepedge.com/products/iphone_charting/)

**Full Disclosure** - I work for Scott Logic, which is the parent company of ShinobiControls

Comment: Hi ColinE, I tried Shinobi and they are lighting fast.  Sadly too limited right now and a bit behind on the looks. Fusion charts are slower (since it's webViews with JS) but beautiful and they have a wide range of charts, including real-time widgets. The best solution for me at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a POC sample created using FusionCharts from http://www.fusioncharts.com/labs/iOS/FusionCharts_iOS_Nov2011.zip.

Comment: Hi Sudimail, I based my app on that exact demo.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[SwiftCharts](https://github.com/i-schuetz/SwiftCharts) has many animated examples and allows to create custom views/animations as well.

(Disclosure: I'm the author)

Comment: You're not a new user, why are you answering a clearly off-topic question?

Comment: There are tons of library-recommendations-questions in this site many of them not closed and very active. And it doesn't seem to be so crearly off-topic as it got only 1 close vote in 4 years. Did you downvote every answer?

Comment: Yes, because I voted to close it just now. The problem is that close votes age away fast.