# How to animate bars of barchart-coreplot

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-plot

I am new to iphone development and coreplot.
I want to draw a barchart according to some data, that i have done.
now i want to give some animations to the bars of plot. That means bars in the graph should lengten or shorten in a growing or shrinking efect.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access CALayer of individual bar in core-plot?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874948/how-to-access-calayer-of-individual-bar-in-core-plot)

Answer (score 1):

Kindly refer the following post:
[How to access CALayer of individual bar in core-plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874948/how-to-access-calayer-of-individual-bar-in-core-plot/9528272#9528272)

It talks about precisely the same thing you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what class you might be using, but most probably it is a subclass of CA Layer.
Check this code out:

```
CABasicAnimation *rotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(360), 0, 0, 1);
rotation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:transform];  
rotation.duration = 10.0f;
[pieChart addAnimation:rotation forKey:@"rotation"];
```

[How to animate the pie charts developed using core-plot library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241740/how-to-animate-the-pie-charts-developed-using-core-plot-library)