# How to access CALayer of individual bar in core-plot?

Tags: ios, calayer, core-plot

I am trying to perform an animation on each bar in the chart, however I am not quite sure how to access the calayer of each individual bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't one. All of the bars are drawn in one layer. If you need to animate them individually, make a separate `CPTBarPlot` (a subclass of `CALayer`) for each bar.

Comment: Came to this conclusion but was praying that I was wrong.
Off topic, but performance would be affected much by having 12 barplots at once?

Comment: Thanks for the assist Eric, great to get help from the maintainer.
What I was attempting was animating the bar values from the current value to the next set of values.
My first idea was to have an invisible set of bars (the new values), let those bar heights and layers be calculated, and transition the current bar frames to the corresponding invisible set's bar frames. But unfortunately the frame/layer of individual bar (and height) is not how core-plot works. Ended up going with fade-out and fade-in on data update.

Answer (score 2):

I have another approach to this considering any performance issues you may face in future if your bars increases. You have a temporary CPTBarPlot with only one bar, to be used just for animation purpose. Use it to perform any animation and remove/hide it once you are done with animation.